# How to read several file types in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read files of several different types. Can I do it in one spark operation? I.e. do it **without** a loop like this:

```py
from pyspark.shell import spark

load_folder = '...'

general_df = None
for extension in ("*.txt", "*.inf"):
    df = spark.read.format("text") \
        .option("pathGlobFilter", extension) \
        .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
        .load(load_folder)
    if general_df is None:
        general_df = df
    else:
        general_df = general_df.union(df)

general_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
from pyspark.shell import spark

load_folder = '...'

df = spark.read.format("text") \
       .option("pathGlobFilter", "{*.txt,*.inf}") \
       .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
       .load(load_folder)

df .show()
```

pathGlobFilter option works based on org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobFilter that seems to be based on bash globbing. Indeed, curly brackets is used there to have multiple possible matches.

```
{*.txt,*.inf} basically is like *.(txt|inf)
```

More info:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-glob-filter
https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/